# How do you compress a directory in Squeak Smalltalk?

Tags: compression, zip, smalltalk, squeak

How do you compress a directory in Squeak Smalltalk? I found the compressFile method in StandardFileStream but I can't figure out how to compress multiple files or a directory. I experimented with the System-Compression classes but haven't had much luck. Thanks in advance!

This is what I have now. I'm adding time stamps at the end of file names, so here I want to put all files that begin with the given file name into a zip or gzip file.

```
compressFile: aFileName in: aDirectory

| zipped buffer unzipped zipFileName |
zipFileName _ aFileName copyUpTo: $. .
zipped _ aDirectory newFileNamed: (zipFileName, FileDirectory dot, 'zip').
zipped binary; setFileTypeToObject.
zipped _ ZipWriteStream on: zipped.
buffer _ ByteArray new: 50000.  
aDirectory fileNames do: [:f |
    (f beginsWith: zipFileName) ifTrue: [
        unzipped _ aDirectory readOnlyFileNamed: (aDirectory fullNameFor: f).
        unzipped binary.
        [unzipped atEnd] whileFalse:[
            zipped nextPutAll: (unzipped nextInto: buffer)].
        unzipped close]].
zipped close.
```

Comment: Could you please post a code snippet which you tried and did not work.

Comment: I just added what I have now. It runs, but when I try to unzip it in terminal I get this error:   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of test1.zip or
        test1.zip.zip, and cannot find test1.zip.ZIP, period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ZipWriteStream` is only a helper class used for compressing, it does not know how a proper ZIP file is layed out, with all the header and directory information etc. You want to use the `ZipArchive` class.

```
"first, construct archive layout in memory"
zip := ZipArchive new.
zip addFile: 'foo.txt'.
zip addFile: 'bar.txt' as: 'xyz.txt'.
zip addTree: dir match: [:entry | entry name beginswith: 'baz'].
"then, write archive to disk, compressing each member"
file := dest newFileNamed: 'test.zip'.
zip writeTo: file.
file close.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think that solution is for Pharo. I can't find a ZipArchive class in Squeak.

Comment: @CharlotteHill which version of squeak? in the 4.x serie ZipArchive is classified under Compression-Archives category

Comment: I'm using version 2, but I'll try upgrading to 4. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, ZipArchive was added after 2.x. If you can use a current Squeak then great, it's a much nicer system. If not, say because you are using a Scratch image which has been heavily customized, then using the ZipArchive from a later version might be your best option. Download http://ftp.squeak.org/3.2/win/Squeak3.2-4956-win-full.zip and  file out the "System-Archives" category, file it into your image, it might just happen to work. Possibly you need the System-Compression category, too.