# Smalltalk (pharo): Using ZipArchive and write to stream instead of file?

Tags: zip, smalltalk, pharo

While I was investigating how to create Zip files in Pharo, I came across this resolved stack overfow's question: [How do you compress a directory in Squeak Smalltalk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18541751/how-do-you-compress-a-directory-in-squeak-smalltalk).

I explored the class, and I found that you can dynamically add strings to it with the method `addString: 'string' as: 'myFile.txt'` (if I am not wrong). So the next and last step, is to output it as an stream, because I want it to be generated on the fly in a seaside's anchor callback, so it is autogenerated and downloaded without creating any temporary file.

I tried many combinations and I just can't get the correct way of handling this. Also, a side question, if the mentioned method, if the string is binary, will it be treated as an string or as binary?

Thanks for the responses.

EDIT: I found the method `writeTo: stream` that should be what I am looking for, just that I don't know which kind of stream to create for it.  `WriteStream with: String new` did not worked. Neither `ByteString new writeStream` I always get `Improper store into indexable object` error

EDIT2: I tried the following code:

```
| z str |
z := ZipArchive new.
z
    addString: someBinaryPNGString as: 'myFile.png';
    addString: someBinaryPNGString as: 'another.png'.
str := "Initialize the stream here somehow"
z writeTo: str
```

Where someBinaryPNGString comes from a base64 text, and the "Initialize the stream here somehow" is the part I am missing.

Is this even the correct way to create on the fly Zip File ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
member := ZipStringMember new contents: 'Hello world'.
zip := #[] writeStream.
member writeTo: zip
^zip contents
```

Comment: I got the same error: Improper store into indexable object :(

Comment: Then something is wrong with your image. The code above works just fine for me (I'm using 5.1-16548-32bit).